# Why Google took off links to Maps from the search engine

Tags: google-search, google-maps

I read a similar question on this site so I know I'm not alone but it seems strange there is no clue around the internet about this issue.
Since a few months, when I perform a site related search on Google, it shows a frame of a map where the place is but this is no longer interactive or clickable. Moreover the direct link to Google maps on top of the google bar has disappeared. It's very annoying.
Someone suggested that it could be that some of us are part of an A/B test but I don't see what benefit would result from this change.
The only possible reason I can imagine about is that Alphabet is reorganizing its products in order to prevent monopoly issues facing at the horizon.

Comment: "Why" is off topic here. "How can I get to the maps tab from search" would be on topic however. You should really [edit] this question to not ask about things that won't be answered here.